# Classes C++. Multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question about multiple inheritance.
I have class A. Class A has several inheritors, for instance B,C,D.

Class X is inheritor of classes B,C,D
How can I pass parameters from the constructor of class X to the constructor of class A?

Answer (score 2):

[Read this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr134.htm) and [this](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/inheritance/intro/)

The way I understand it, you have your objects set up like this, where X is the super class of all:

```
   X
  /|\
 B C D
  \|/
   A
```

You can chain the constructors. So, in the definition to constructor of class X, pass the data needed to construct B,C,D, and those construct X as needed.

See [this example C++ code](http://codepad.org/QrAst2Wv) post that exemplifies what you are wanting to do.

I should note, however, that there are some issues with your inheritance scheme. In most cases, it is better to prefer composition to inheritance. You might want to ask yourself what relationship between the objects you are defining: is B an X, C an X and D an X? or does B have an X? C? D? Ask the same about A. When you finish, you might reorganize your code so that this is not relevant. However, in the case that you find that this organization is unavoidable, you might want to reference some authoritative source on C++ about how objects manage their superclass data. In this case, I think A may possess three instances of X. Some extra work may be required to ensure that A only possesses a single common X ancestor among B, C, and D. That I don't know off the top of my head...

Comment: B, C, and D must inherit virtually from A for X to only have one copy.

Comment: Another issue is that the B, C, D constructors would have to pass the parameters to X. They might not do so. Having to know the details of a "grandparent" class is asking for trouble.

Comment: Mooing Duck,
Adam Miller,
juanchopanza,
Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Yes, thanks mooing duck.

Comment: @AdamMiller give that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673754/pe-format-iat-questions/7678496#7678496 as your own answer instead doing redial editing

Comment: what is "redial" editing? I'll do it, but please explain